# jQuery Insert, then fade out and then remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadeout, insertafter

I am verifying the form, and if there are problems I am adding a message right after input with problem & then fade it out after some time. The thing is I would like to also remove that message from DOM.

I googled a bit and it looks like I have to use `fadeout(function(){})` or queue. Well, that would be ok in other case, but as I am inserting it and removing with same line, its a bit more tricky. Is there some other simpler "one line" way?

I tried to add another (longer delay), but that does not work at all.

```
$("<div style='color: red'>Maximum length is "+$(this).attr('maxlength')+" characters!</div>").insertAfter($(this)).delay(5000).fadeOut().delay(5010).remove();
```

I can't also really use IDs, as it can throw multiple ones at same time or user can just quicky fix one input and click submit and it would remove old and new message at same time.

Thanks.

Ps.: Only way to do it I can think of is generating random ID for every element and using that ID to remove it, but thats just way too overcomplicated IMHO.

For clarification: That line above is inside a loop that loops trough every input and textarea in a form and they are just simple if checks for minlength, maxlength and numbers only. Thats why I can't put there some static ID/Class, it would not really work as I want it to (remove ONLY that added element, no others, even if there was same message added again as user submits form again etc.). Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Each error message is related to a field I think, Therefore You can assign an Id to each error message without any problem. So this code can be useful:

```
  $("<div style='color: red' id="FieldName_error">Maximum length is "+$(this).attr('maxlength')+" characters!</div>").insertAfter($(this));

 //This function executes after 2 seconds.
 setTimeout(function(){
    $("#FieldName_error").fadeOut("slow", function(){
        $(this).remove();
    })
 }, 2000)
```

Comment: Not really. That line is inside a loop that checks every input in whole form and I have multiple of them (for maxlength, minlength, only numeric etc.). If I did message for every input separately, the code would be about 10 times longer or more.